# Can this theorem be extended thus?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

Consider the theorem:

> If $f$ is a continuous and differentiable real-function over an interval $I$ and $f'(x)\ge 0$ on $I,$ then $f$ does not decrease over $I.$

Somehow, I expect this to be true even if $f$ is not differentiable at some points in $I,$ so long as these points are at most countable. I think I expect this to be the case because of the continuity, but I have no way to prove this rigorously. Any help would be appreciated. An example of a function like what I mean is $$\frac{x}{1+x \left|\sin \frac 1x \right|},$$ for $0<x<1.$

**PS.** I'd especially appreciate a proof that made use of no more than MVT and the conditions in the other theorem, as this will justify the *intuition* I have that these ingredients are what make the theorem extensible to this case, too.

Comment: @Chrystomath That function is not differentiable at uncountably many points.

Comment: @Allawonder Integrate the derivative. The integral doesn't care about the values (or lack of them) at countably many points.

Comment: Ay how many points is f(x) = 0 if x irrational, f(n/m) = 1/m for coprime n,m and positive m, differentiable?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I don't understand your question. I'm not trying to count points where the function is differentiable. I want to be able to tell by examining the derivative of a function that is differentiable almost everywhere on an interval whether the function is monotonic on that interval.

Comment: @user647486 How should that help me *prove* that the original function is monotonic over that interval, seeing that the such an integral would not exist at some points, whereas the original function does.

Comment: If the points where f' does not exist are countable, then f is a counterexample. @Allawonder

Comment: If $f'$ exists all but countably many points of $I=[a,b]$, and $f'(x)\geq0$ at the points where it exists, then $f'$ is integrable (Lebesgue or Henstock–Kurzweil integrable). Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus: For $x>y$, $x,y\in I$, we have $f(x)-f(y)=\int_{y}^{x}f'(x)dx\geq0$. Therefore, $f$ is not decreasing.

Comment: @WilliamElliot No, I don't think so. For example, over which interval is your function continuous and differentiable ae?

Comment: @user647486 Great. Although I did not think of proving this via integrals (I was reading a section on the usual first derivative test in optimization, which uses no more than MVT, so I was tacitly constraining myself to these conditions), I think you have essentially answered my question. Will you write it up as an answer?

Comment: @user647486 Although I'd still appreciate a proof that uses no more than MVT and continuity. I somehow have the intuition that these works because of the continuity, and was wondering how I could wield that, together with MVT, to prove it.

Comment: [Cantor staircase function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) shows that in a generalization a condition $f’(x)\ge 0$ at all but countable many points  cannot be replaced by a condition $f’(x)\ge 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I don't understand why not; is any set of countable points not meagre?

Comment: Right, and so the conditions  $f’(x)\ge 0$ almost everywhere or on $I$ without a meager set are weaker than  $f’(x)\ge 0$ at all but countable many points of $I$, and these weaker conditions do not guarantee that $f$ does not decrease over $I$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Oh, I see. Seems you're trying to point out that *meagre* and *countable* may sometimes not be equivalent. I was only using the former in the cases where it also implies the latter, but I grant that what you point out is true.